# constructor Rational in class Rational cannot be applied to the given types?

Tags: java, constructor, rational-number, fractions

So the gist of this program is to create a Rational class so that when you run it, a GUI input will come up and ask for a numerator and a denominator. It will then return the reduced fraction. But I keep getting this error message and I don't know why. Here's the program so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class lab8
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String strNbr1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Numerator ");
    String strNbr2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Denominator ");

    int num = Integer.parseInt(strNbr1);
    int den = Integer.parseInt(strNbr2);

    Rational r = new Rational(num,den);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,r.getNum()+"/"+r.getDen()+" equals "+r.getDecimal());

    System.exit(0);
}
}



class Rational
{
private int num;
private int den;

public Rational()
{
    num = 0;
    den = 1;
}
public double getNum()
{
    return num;
}

public int getDen()
{
    return den;
}
 }
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?  Which line of code is it referring to?

Comment: it is "constructor Rational in class Rational cannot be applied to the given types;"

Comment: The error message will refer to a particular line of code; which is it?

Comment: it's referring to the Rational class

Comment: Rational r = new Rational(num,den);

Comment: Simply modify your constructor signature to take in two integer arguments.                                                                 Rational(int,int)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to call a constructor that doesn't exist.
Your class constructor asks for nothing:

```
public Rational()
```

while it should ask for 2 ints:

```
public Rational(int num, int den){
     this.num = num;
     this.den = den;
}
```

so you can pass both `num` and `den` to it as you are trying to do in

```
Rational r = new Rational(num,den);
```